# How can I fix this type mess of nested fmap functors?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, nested, functor, map-function

```
data Color = White | Black deriving (Eq, Show)
data Role = King | Queen | Rook deriving (Eq, Show)

data Piece = Piece { color :: Color, 
                     role  :: Role } deriving (Eq)

data Piese = Piese { piece :: Piece,
                     coord :: Coord } deriving (Eq)

data ColorMap a = ColorMap {
    white :: a,
    black :: a
  } deriving (Eq)

instance Functor ColorMap where
  fmap fn (ColorMap white black) = 
    ColorMap (fn white) (fn black)

colorMapFromList :: (a -> Color) -> [a] -> ColorMap [a]
colorMapFromList fn lst = ColorMap 
    (filter ((== White) . fn) lst)
    (filter ((== Black) . fn) lst)
                  
data RoleMap a = RoleMap {
    king  :: a,
    queen :: a,
    rook  :: a }

instance Functor RoleMap where
  fmap fn (RoleMap king queen rook) = 
    RoleMap (fn king) (fn queen) (fn rook)

roleMapFromList :: (a -> Role) -> [a] -> RoleMap [a]
roleMapFromList fn lst = RoleMap
    (filter ((== King ) . fn) lst)
    (filter ((== Queen) . fn) lst)
    (filter ((== Rook ) . fn) lst)

mapso :: [Piese] -> ColorMap (RoleMap [Coord])
mapso lst = 
 fmap (fmap (fmap coord))                -- ColorMap (RoleMap [Coord])
   (fmap (roleMapFromList (role . piece))  -- ColorMap (RoleMap [Piese])
         (colorMapFromList (color . piece)   -- ColorMap [Piese]
              lst))                            -- [Piese]
```

I've just jumped into Haskell, this compiles, but it seems error prone to me. Is there a pattern here I can simplify this into? Specifically the `mapso` function.

Comment: What do you do with `ColorMap (RoleMap [Coord])` that you need ColorMap and RoleMap?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what I am doing, I am just learning. Some way to group the data so it's easily understandable like for making a chess AI.

Comment: You may want to look into traverse https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:traverse.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the fact that functors compose. While you can represent this fairly explicitly by defining new types with `Data.Functor.Compose`, practically speaking it just means that you can compose `fmap` with itself.

```
mapso :: [Piese] -> ColorMap (RoleMap [Coord])
mapso lst = fmap (fmap (fmap coord))
  (fmap (roleMapFromList (role.piece)) (colorMapFromList (color.piece) lst))
```

becomes

```
mapso = (fmap . fmap . fmap) coord . 
        fmap (roleMapFromList (role.piece)) .
        colorMapFromList (color.piece)
```

or with some refactoring:

```
mapso = let fffmap = fmap . fmap . fmap
            makeColorMap = colorMapFromList (color.piece)
            makeRoleMap = roleMapFromList (role.piece)
        in fffmap coord . 
           fmap makeRoleMap .
           makeColorMap
```

I've switched to a point-free form to highlight the three stages:

1. Create the `ColorMap`
2. Create the `RoleMap`
3. Map `coord` over the `[Piese]` value wrapped inside the `RoleMap` wrapped inside the `ColorMap`.

We use function composition to reduce the amount of explicit nesting in the definition of `mapso`.

If you aren't comfortable thinking in terms of function composition yet, you can just define more temporary variables in the `let` expression:

```
mapso lst = let fffmap = fmap . fmap . fmap
                makeColorMap = colorMapFromList (color.piece)
                makeRoleMap = fmap (roleMapFromList (role.piece))
            in let colorMap = makeColorMap lst
                   rolemap = makeRoleMap colorMap
            in fffmap coord roleMap
```

(Do we need two `let` expressions? No. But it might be helpful to separate the helper functions from the values the helper functions compute.)

Comment: IMO `fmap` should be taken out from the `makeRoleMap`'s definition, to restore the symmetry with `makeColorMap`. ---- also, the three stages are seen just fine by just adding some proper indentation to the OP code.

Comment: Ah, you , mean shift it down into the "main" expression, like `fffmap coord . fmap makeRoleMap . makeColorMap`?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make your maps `Monoid` instances. So:

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (RoleMap a) where
    RoleMap ks qs rs <> RoleMap ks' qs' rs' = 
        RoleMap (ks <> ks') (qs <> qs') (rs <> rs')
instance Monoid a => Monoid (RoleMap a) where 
    mempty = RoleMap mempty mempty mempty

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (ColorMap a) where
    ColorMap ws bs <> ColorMap ws' bs' = 
        ColorMap (ws <> ws') (bs <> bs')
instance Monoid a => Monoid (ColorMap a) where 
    mempty = ColorMap mempty mempty
```

Now, instead of filtering, provide a function that creates singleton maps.

```
singletonRole :: Monoid a => Role -> a -> RoleMap a
singletonRole r a = case r of
    King  -> mempty { king  = a }
    Queen -> mempty { queen = a }
    Rook  -> mempty { rook  = a }

singletonColor :: Monoid a => Color -> a -> ColorMap a
singletonColor c a = case c of
    White -> mempty { white = a }
    Black -> mempty { black = a }
```

Using these, it's easy to write a function that consumes a single `Piese`:

```
singletonFromPiese :: Piese -> ColorMap (RoleMap [Coord])
singletonFromPiese (Piese p c) = 
    singletonColor (color p) . 
        singletonRole (role p) $ [c]
```

Consuming lots of `Piese`s is just a `foldMap`:

```
mapso :: [Piese] -> ColorMap (RoleMap [Coord])
mapso = foldMap singletonFromPiese
```

One thing that's nice about this approach is that, to me, each individual piece of code looks obvious and doesn't require mental type inference. Nested `fmap`s -- even if we think of them as a single `fmap` on a composed type -- don't have that property, at least for me.

Another nice property is that we make only one pass over the list; in the obvious implementation of the `fmap` version, we make three passes for the three filters of creating a `RoleMap` and two passes for the two filters of creating a `ColorMap`, for a total of five passes.

Comment: your approach is also more modular. ---- it's arguably not too difficult to replace the separate filter passes with one partition pass, for a total of two partition passes (one by color, the other by role). also perhaps worth noticing that foldMap being right-associative avoids what would otherwise be a quadratic behavior.