# I need a monad solution to a functor simplification

Tags: haskell

This extends from a solution I have used for my [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69092450/how-can-i-fix-this-type-mess-of-nested-fmap-functors/69093246#69093246)

```
data CoroMap a = CoroMap (ColorMap (RoleMap a))


instance Functor CoroMap where
  fmap fn (CoroMap coro) =
    CoroMap $ fmap (fmap fn) coro


visions:: Piese -> [Vision]
visions p = []

ihavethis :: CoroMap [Piese]
ineedthis:: CoroMap [Vision]
-- ineedthis = ???


-- I have this a ->  [b]
-- I need this [a] -> [b]

-- specifically converting CoroMap [Piese] to CoroMap [Vision] 
-- using Piese -> [Vision]
```

Comment: `concatMap` (aka `>>=` or "bind" for the List monad) will do precisely this: convert a function of type `a -> [b]` to one of type `[a] -> [b]`. I do not know whether it will have the actual effect you want, however.

Comment: I think this worked, so if you make it an answer I will accept it:
`fmap (concatMap visions) ihavethis :: CoroMap [Vision]`

Comment: Although if I were to write a generic function for this conversion, where would I put it.

Comment: I need this function `f [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> f [b]`

Comment: happy to put this as an answer, but not quite sure I follow the second part of - what you mean by "a generic function for this conversion", or what you are asking when you say "where would I put it".

Comment: assuming `f` is a functor, then that function is precisely `g as f = fmap (concatMap g) as`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have this a ->  [b]
>
> I need this [a] -> [b]

A lot of questions like this in Haskell basically boil down to "following the types" - meaning that (sometimes, although not always) you don't have to think too hard about what you actually want the function to *do*, you just need the types to match up. (This might seem rather miraculous, and in a way it is - it's due to the fact that types in Haskell give you so much information compared to many other statically-typed languages.) And the ability to pick a function which has the right type often simply comes with a bit of experience.

Even if you don't have much experience, there is a very good way to "cheat" - go to [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) and type in the type signature you are interested in. Here, entering

```
(a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

and letting it search will bring up a lot of relevant results, of which the very first is [concatMap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:concatMap). This is the function that, given such a function of type `a -> [b]` and a list of type `[a]`, first maps the function over the list, resulting in a list of lists (`[[b]]`), then concatenates those together to get a simple `[b]`. That's very likely what you want (and seems to be the case, based on your response to my comment suggesting it).

In terms of being able to spot this without needing a helper like Hoogle - Monads are ubiquitous in Haskell, and lists are one of many very common type which form a monad. Seeing therefore that you have a `a -> m b` (for a particular monad `m`) and want a `m a -> m b`, any Haskeller with a little bit of experience will instantly think of the fundamental method of the `Monad` typeclass, which is `(>>=)` (pronounced "bind"), and has type

```
(Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

This is very close to what you want, the only difference is that you have to flip it, to get:

```
flip (>>=) :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

which due to currying (aka "arrows in type signatures are right-associative"), is the same as

```
flip (>>=) :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> (m a -> m b)
```

which is exactly what you asked for, only it will work for all Monads, not just lists. That's how I came up with `concatMap`, because `(>>=)` for lists is defined to be `flip concatMap`, so the `flip (>>=)` that you want is simply `concatMap`.

Note also that the Hoogle search I mentioned above lists `(=<<)` a short way down - that's just an abbreviation for `flip (>>=)`. So this all marries up nicely.

Finally, for your bonus question:

> I need this function `f [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> f [b]`

where from context `f` is a `Functor` - this is just a case of combining what we already have:

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> ([a] -> [b])`
```

with `fmap`. Given `g :: a -> [b]` we know `concatMap g` is of type `[a] -> [b]`, so `fmap (concatMap g)` is of type `f [a] -> f [b]`. In other words, `\g -> fmap (concatMap g)` (which you can also write as `fmap . concatMap`) has type `(a -> [b]) -> f [a] -> f [b]`, so we simply need to apply swap the arguments. So the function you want is

```
flip (fmap . concatMap)
```

in pointfree form, or if you prefer explicit arguments (which looks less elegant but is often easier to understand), you can write it as

```
\as g -> fmap (concatMap g) as
```

Comment: I don't understand the `flip` because it just works like this:
`(fmap . concatMap) visions` or this also works `fmap . flip (>>=) $ visions`

Comment: @eguneys As Robin says, you can use `concatMap`, or you can use `flip (>>=)`, which is equivalent but more general.

Comment: But he has written this `flip (fmap . concatMap)` , which doesn't work

Comment: how do you mean, "doesn't work"? The type of that function is precisely `f [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> f [b]` for `f` a functor (well actually it's slightly more general, GHCi gives it as `(Functor f, Foldable t) => f (t a) -> (a -> [b]) -> f [b]`, but since the List type is an instance of `Foldable` it specialises to the one I gave)

Comment: I am confused by how functions become functors into the type system, so you separate my two questions and give two different answers, I thought they are the same.

Comment: Well the two functions you were asking for are very similar - as I said in the answer, the second is just applying `fmap` to the first and with an additional `flip` because you happened to ask the second question with the arguments in the opposite order. And I only gave a "separate" answer because you explicitly asked that second question after I'd already answered the first (in the comments). I'm not sure what else you expected.